# What is the purpose of creating an abstract class function

Tags: delphi

In Delphi I often see code like this :

```
TmyClass = class
public
   class function getSomething: integer; virtual; abstract;
end;
```

But what is the purpose of such declaration (ie: class function), because calling `TmyClass.getSomething` will always fail as it is not implemented, even if it is implemented in a child class.

Comment: Iirc,`Abstract` was originally introduced in D2 to assist its support of interfaces for automation/COM.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It fails if you call `TmyClass.getSomething` directly, but it can be useful in combination with metaclasses. It gives you opportunity to define abstract API just like it would on non class functions.

For instance:

```
TmyClassClass = class of TMyClass;

TmyClass1 = class(TmyClass)
public
   class function getSomething: integer; override;
end;

var
  c: TmyClassClass;

  c := TmyClass1;
  c.getSomething;
```

---

Of course, you can always use class functions on object instances, so calling `getSomething` on `TMyClass1` object instance will work, too.

Comment: And you don't even need to use metaclasses this explicitly. If you create an *instance* of a `TmyClass1`, you may also invoke its (class') overridden `getSomething`.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Yes, but then it is not as obvious why it would be class function.

Comment: I agree (but of course there are situations when such an approach is sound and valid).